# What site would be best to ask about Verifone customization?

Tags: support, business

I have a question about Verifone terminal and swiper devices. I want to customize them but don't know how nor know where to ask in Stack Exchange. Help?

Answer (score 2):

The configuration/maintenance of Verifone terminals sometimes falls under the IT department, so you may want to ask if such devices are on-topic on [Server Fault's meta support](http://meta.serverfault.com).

Or maybe someone here can confirm or refute whether it's in scope.

Comment: from looking around that site, questions about credit card machines and terminals I doubt would be off topic. Thanks for your help

Comment: I asked it there, one person said that I should consult the Reference guide and that the question was off topic